# Is there a series that is asymptotic to $\log(\log(\log x))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

We know: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\dfrac{1}{n}\sim\log(x)$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\dfrac{1}{\text{prime}(n)}\sim\log(\log(x))$.

I wonder if there is another interesting series that diverges even slower than reciprocals of primes, at a rate of $\log(\log(\log x))$. Or perhaps if there is a family of series that diverge ever more slowly, that are asymptotic to $\log(x)$ nested once, twice, thrice, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), $\text{prime(n)}\sim n\log(n)$. Therefore

$$\sum^x_{n=1}\frac{1}{\text{prime}(n)\log\Big(\frac{\text{prime}(n)}{n}\Big)}\sim \int_3^x \frac{1}{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))}\,dn\sim\log(\log(\log(x)))$$
In a similar way, you can obtain  more examples (though not so "interesting" I guess...).

Comment: I was imagining something along the lines of "subset of reciprocals of primes" gives triple nested logx, just as "subset of reciprocals of integers" gives double nested logx.

Comment: Maybe something involving the twin primes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Brun's_theorem

Comment: @GappyHilmore - since the triple $\log(x)$ goes to infinity when $x$ does, the according series must diverge. I think, I have seen a statement like that using the twinprimes the series becomes convergent instead.